# Fuzzy string matching in Python for structured strings?

Tags: nlp, string-matching, fuzzy-comparison

I have a Python implementation of fuzzy matching using the Levenshtein similarity. I'm pretty happy with it but I feel I'm leaving a lot on the table by not considering the structure of the strings.

Here are some examples of matches that are clearly good, but not captured well by Levenshtein :

- `The Hobbit`  / `Hobbit/The`
- `Charlies Angles` / `Charlie's Angels`
- `Apples & Pairs` / `Apples and Pairs`

I think some normalization ahead of using Levenshtein would be good - eg. replace all `&` with `and`, remove punctuation, etc...  not sure I want to jump straight to stop-word removal and lematization, but something along those line

To avoid re-inventing the wheel, is there any easy way to do this? Or an alternative to levenshtine that addresses these issues (short of some Bert embeddings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rapidfuzz.utils.default_process` might be an option to consider for preprocessing.

> **rapidfuzz.utils.default_process**(sentence: str) → str
> This function preprocesses a string by:
>
> - removing all non alphanumeric characters
> - trimming whitespaces
> - converting all characters to lower case
>
> PARAMETERS:
> **sentence** (str) – String to preprocess
>
> RETURNS:
> **processed_string** – processed string
>
> RETURN TYPE:
> str

https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/utils.html

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use some preporcessing like below and Remove non-alphanumeric characters or convert all to lowercasess or extra spaces:

```
def preprocess_string(s):
    s = s.lower()
    
    s = s.replace('&', 'and')
    
    s = re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9 ]', '', s)
    
    s = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s).strip()

    s = re.sub(r'&', 'and', s).strip()
    
    return s
```

in fact preprocessing is always crucial for this kind of comparison.

Comment: I'm looking for some standard application of these replacements, I'd rather not re-invent all normalizations.